# I have two ngIf conditions. How I can make them an ngIf else?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-ng-if

I have two `<div>` with `*ngIf`. They are kind of large, so I am having trouble implementing an `*ngIf else` while reading the documentation, because I am unsure where to put so much content.

I have two open text boxes. I thought using the exact same styling and if one was hidden and the other visible, they would both be in the same position, obviously I was wrong.

Here are the two `<div>`:

```
          <!--open text box if language control is true-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.visibility]="showLanguageControl === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-5" for="providerRoute">Linked Language Letter</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-7 padding-adj">
            <input type="text" id="linkedLetter" name="linkedLetter" #linkedLetter formControlName="linkedLetter" [ngClass]="['form-control','input-xs']" />
        </div>
    </div>

          <!--open text box if exception group is true-->
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" [style.visibility]="showFaxNumberInput === true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-5" for="providerRoute">Fax Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-7 padding-adj">
           <input type="text" id="faxInput" name="faxInput" #faxInput formControlName="faxInput" [ngClass]="['form-control','input-xs']" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Confused here. I don’t see an *ngIf..?

Answer (score 4):

To turn `*ngIf` into `if-else` you can either use `*ngIf` twice negating condition (!something) for the `else` case, or you can use the following approach:

```html
<div *ngIf="condition else showThis">
    True
</div>
<ng-template #showThis>
    False
</ng-template>
```

- `condition` - is something that resolves to `boolean`;
- `showThis` - is a local reference to the template.